# how to implement OpenID via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, openid

I want to implement a login system by using openid (for login with google, yahoo) for asp.net and asp.net mvc applications, I search over the Internet (and googled that and also stacked :D) but, there is nothing to guide me to implement this; all pages was about libraries (DotNetOpenId, DotNetOpenAuth, etc);
can anybody help me to understanding and implementing this? without other libraries? thanks.

Comment: Why not use something that has already been field tested, with security holes patched, bugs fixed, and feature rich?

Comment: because I want to understand openid protocol, not just use it.

Comment: I'm going to code myself to enable Google authentication for a website of mine now, and I don't want DotNetOpenAuth too just because it's a bit complex than what I want and I don't need all its features, I just need Google way.

Comment: use this link: `http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html` I am agree with you, and I implemented it by myself. Good luck.

Comment: **FROM OP** : thanks friends, I found my answer, I found a complete explain by yahoo and google on this pages, and put them here, if other users need it: [google](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html),  [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/request-token.html)